# page cache is invalidated after the "Category Products" index is reindexed

Tags: magento2.3.4

i have problem when the cronjob run, the page cache is invalidated after the "Category Products" index is reindexed.

- this problem happens exactly after each 30min (time of cron job) the FPC become invalidated
- -there is no changes or updates to products, categories, catalog price rules, static blocks, 3rd party extensions, etc.
- there is no visitor to website as its under construction
- there is more than 100K product on website

**We use:**

- magento 2.3.4
- PHP version 7.2
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64)
- VPS Cloud hosting
- the cpanel cron job -> https://ibb.co/Wg9v2b1

Any idea/solution?
Regards
Gabriel

Comment: Magento 2,there should be some  code at 3rd party module dodging this

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to 'warm' the cache for products that require it. Visiting the page using cURL or Wget would do the job or using one of the multitude of 'cache warmer' scripts available online.

Alternatively, a more intelligent method of reindexing, based on necessity, rather than schedule, would stop the cache being cleared unless there has been some change in your catalogue.

I don't know about M2 but in M1 you could selectively reindex based on need

```
    $processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
      ->getProcessesCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'require_reindex')
      ->getColumnValues('indexer_code');
    foreach ($processes as $process) {
      try {
        $process->reindexEverything();
        Mage::dispatchEvent($process->getIndexerCode() . '_shell_reindex_after');
      } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
      }
```